# JS Drop Down Menu to appear over Image Rotator

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, z-index

hoping someone can help me out with this. I'm trying to get the drop down menu to appear over the javascript image slider on this page...

http://www.spektroskopy.com/SNSv2/index.php

I seem to remember coming across this issue ages back but for the life of me i can't seem to find a solution, i even had a play around with z-index.. but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a CSS issue, in navigation.css line 52 you will find `.dropmenu li ul, .dropmenu li > div` add there `z-index:2`